# export Data in localStorage for later re-import

Tags: javascript, import, export, local-storage

I want to export a few items from my localStorage to save it externally but in a format so that I can import it again later.

My attempt was to write executable code that can be pasted later in a textarea. Then the value of that textare will simply be eval()ed.

Problem: The data stored in localStorage were stored as

```js
var data = [];
data.push('sampledata');
data.push({sample: 'object'});
localStorage.setItem('varname',data);
```

So it contains various chars I don't like, like ', " etc

My (not working) solution so far was:

```js
var container = $('#localDataContainer');
container.append('localStorage.setItem("cockpitLastVisited","' + localStorage.getItem("cockpitLastVisited") + '");<br/>');
container.append('localStorage.setItem("cockpit_services","' + localStorage.getItem("cockpit_services") + '");<br/>');
container.append('localStorage.setItem("cockpit_users","' + localStorage.getItem("cockpit_users") + '");');
```

If my attempt seems to be OK, what is the best way to create code that can then be executed the way it is?

Comment: just in case someone needs a chrome extension solution: try [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can encode Objects into Strings using JSON.stringify (object to String) and decode Strings into Objects using JSON.parse (String to Object).

Write to localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("varname",JSON.stringify(originalVarname));
```

Read from localStorage

```
var originalVarname= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("varname"));
```

Answer (score 76):

Here's how to import/export your entire localStorage

**Export**

```
copy(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
```

This will copy your localStorage to your clipboard. (You need two JSON.stringify()'s to get the quotes escaped.)

**Import**

```
var data = JSON.parse(/*paste stringified JSON from clipboard*/);
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
  localStorage.setItem(k, JSON.stringify(data[k]));
});
```

Comment: For importing we need two JSON.parse() as well

Comment: Hm, shouldn't that be: `localStorage.setItem(k, JSON.stringify(data[k]))` so that the data goes back into local storage as strings?

Comment: @EFC Using `JSON.stringly` can cause trouble by adding unwanted quotes.

Answer (score 33):

Just an improved version of Jeremy. To simplify the process

```
copy('var data = '+JSON.stringify(localStorage)+';Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k){localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]);});');
```

Run this in console where you need to export, it copies localstorage content along with code to clipboard and just paste it in the console where you want to import.

Answer (score 14):

**Export**

```
copy(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(localStorage)));
```

**Import**

```
var data = JSON.parse(/*previously copied stringified JSON from clipboard*/);
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
  localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]);
});
```

Comment: I needed to stringify twice as above. One time stringification did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just a modernized version of [@iceLord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473783) answer.

Just run this in the console, it will put the code to restore the localStorage back into your clipboard.

```js
copy(`Object.entries(${JSON.stringify(localStorage)})
.forEach(([k,v])=>localStorage.setItem(k,v))`)
```

Bookmarklet version

```js
javascript:prompt(`localStorage from ${location.host}${new Date().toLocaleString()}`, `/* localStorage from ${location.host}${new Date().toLocaleString()}*/Object.entries(  ${JSON.stringify(localStorage)}).forEach(([k,v])=>localStorage.setItem(k,v))`)
```